# Is there any tool or technique that allows solving a system of 8 quadratic equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'm looking for a tool, or at least technique, that allows me to solve the following system of equations:

```
 a*a +  a*b +  a*c +  a*d +  a*e +  a*f +  a*g +  a*h = 0
 b*b +  b*a +  b*d +  b*c +  b*f +  b*e +  b*h +  b*g = 0
 c*c + -c*d +  c*a + -c*b +  c*g + -c*h +  c*e + -c*f = 0
-d*d +  d*c + -d*b +  d*a + -d*h +  d*g + -d*f +  d*e = 1
 e*e + -e*f + -e*g + -e*h +  e*a + -e*b + -e*c + -e*d = 0
-f*f +  f*e +  f*h + -f*g + -f*b +  f*a +  f*d + -f*c = 0
-g*g +  g*h +  g*e +  g*f + -g*c +  g*d +  g*a +  g*b = 0
-h*h +  h*g +  h*f +  h*e + -h*d +  h*c +  h*b +  h*a = 0
```

For integers `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`. I've tried Wolfram Alpha, but the system is too large, it exceeds the character limit. Is there any alternative tool that can help me solve this particular problem?

Comment: @Abezhiko This comes from the square of a 3D geometric algebra element, or rather, I'm trying to solve `x^2 = XY`, where `x` is a rank-3 multivector. $a = b = c = d = e = f = g = 0$ isn't a solution since it will fail for the 4th equation! Also keep in mind I'm looking for integer solutions.

Comment: The fourth equations says $dm=1$ for $m=-d+c+\cdots +e$. So $d=\pm 1$, which gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system can be easily solved by applying Gröbner bases.
One solution is given by $a=b=c=e=f=g=h=0$ and $d^2+1=0$, so $d=\pm i$.
Another one is given by
$c=e=f=g=h=0$, and
$$d=\frac{1}{2a},\; b=-\frac{2a^2+1}{2a}$$
for nonzero $a$. There are exactly $7$ such types of solutions. None of them is integral. But the system has rational solutions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed what tool you used, or how you achieved that result (if you did it by hand), as I'm not familiar with Grobner bases. But great answer never the less. Thank you.

Comment: I used a Gröbner basis package (usually contained in a CAS). But you can do it by hand, if you are only looking for integer solutions. We have $dm=1$, so either $d=1$ or $d=-1$. In both cases, you will obtain a fraction $1/2$ appearing in another variable, so not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The only truly quadratic equation is the $4^{th}$ one, the others are vanishing products of linear factors which can be solved by considering the different subcases.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> a (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h) = 0 \tag{1}
> \\ b(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h) = 0 \tag{2}
> \\ c(a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h) = 0 \tag{3}
> \\ d(a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h) = 1 \tag{4}
> \\ e(a - b - c - d + e - f - g - h) = 0 \tag{5}
> \\ f(a - b - c + d + e - f - g + h) = 0 \tag{6}
> \\ g(a + b - c + d + e + f - g + h) = 0 \tag{7}
> \\ h(a + b + c - d + e + f + g - h) = 0 \tag{8}
> \end{align}
> $$

Equation $(4)$ implies that $a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h \ne 0$, then $(3)$ implies $c=0$.

- If $\require{cancel}a + b + \color{gray}{\cancel{c}} + d + e + f + g + h = 0$ then equation $(7)$ reduces to $-2g^2=0 \implies g=0$. 
  Then equations $(4),(5)$ reduce to $2d(a+e)=1$ and $2e(a+e)=0 \implies e=0, 2ad = 1$. 
  The system then becomes:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  a + b + d + f + h = 0
  \\ 2ad = 1 \tag{4'}
  \\ f(a + d + h) = 0 \tag{6'}
  \\ h(d + h) = 0 \tag{8'}
  \end{align}
  $$
- If $\require{cancel}a + b + \color{gray}{\cancel{c}} + d + e + f + g + h \ne 0$ then equations $(1)-(2)$ imply $a=b=0$. 
  The system then becomes:
  \begin{align}
  \\ d(- d + e - f + g - h) = 1 \tag{4''}
  \\ e(- d + e - f - g - h) = 0 \tag{5''}
  \\ f(d + e - f - g + h) = 0 \tag{6''}
  \\ g(d + e + f - g + h) = 0 \tag{7''}
  \\ h(- d + e + f + g - h) = 0 \tag{8''}
  \end{align}

In both cases, the systems can be solved by further breaking down the different subcases. There don't appear to exist integer solutions, though.